# Python import behaviour and 'NoneType' object has no attribute

Tags: python, python-import

Can anyone clarify the following behavior. I ran into it in a bigger piece of code, but I created a minimal example

File `untitled0.py` consists of the following code:

```
import numpy as np
class A:
    def f(self,x):
        return np.diag(x)
```

File `untitled1.py` consists of the following code:

```
import untitled0 as u0
import numpy as np
a=u0.A()
print a.f([1])
```

The output is simple and [[1]] is printed on the screen. Now suppose you have created `a` (an instance of A) with a lot of computational effort and continue writing your script and don't want to recompute all the time. What I then normally do is simply commenting out the creation line (since the object a is already exists in you python shell anyway), i.e.:

```
import untitled0 as u0
import numpy as np
#a=u0.A()
print a.f([1])
```

However, when I run this script it leads to the error:

```
UMD has deleted: untitled0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\WinPython-64bit-2.7.5.1\python-2.7.5.amd64\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell   \sitecustomize.py", line 523, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "M:\....\untitled1.py", line 12, in <module>
    print a.f([1])
  File "untitled0.py", line 12, in f
    return np.diag(x)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'diag'
```

For some reason `np` is not defined inside `untitled0.py`. Can anyone explain what happened?

Comment: How are you invoking this code? What sort of Python environment are you using?

Comment: You can do `$pip freeze` to see if `numpy` is installed in your python environment

Comment: I am using the spyder ide in winpython 2.7.5.1. Within spyder scripts are started in a python shell (not ipython, but a normal shell) with nympy and scipy already imported. Numpy is definitely installed, because I can make scripts that create numpy arrays and use the numpy routines on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line "UMD has deleted ..." is the hint.  You are likely using the Spyder IDE, and this non-standard behavior is described here: [Spyder - UMD has deleted: module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13876306/spyder-umd-has-deleted-module)

Now the additional issue is that the module untitled0.py has been unloaded (and reloaded).  However, your pre-existing instance `a` has a class that is the one that existed in the *old copy* of the module.  So its method `f()` invokes the *old version* of the code.  The problem here is that the old copy of the module was garbage-collected: this means (strangely enough) that Python has replaced all global names with None.  This is why you end up with looking up `np.diag()` --- but crashing because `np` is None at this point.

Why does it replace all global variables with None???  It's a very old reason: because it creates cycles of references, and Once Upon a Time Long Ago such cycles used to create memory leaks.  It hasn't been cleaned up since.

I'm sorry not to have a concrete advice about how to avoid the problem, but I hope this is enough to explain the how's and why's.  I guess that further discussion should go with the Spyder guys, where you should report the problem and how it shows up.

Answer (score -2):

when you do

```
a.f([1])
```

while commenting

```
 #a = u0.A()
```

what happens is that a is not instantiated . when a does not exist , it is not possible to call its methods . thats why the interpreter throws a "NoneType" attribute has no method named diag. instead of having to recompute the results everytime try storing the results in a by changing the behaviour of f; for eg

```
class A:
    def f(self,no):
      self.result = np.diag(no)
      return self.result
```

and then do

```
a = u0.A()
#use a 
a.f(some_list)
```

Comment: Your diagnosis is wrong, if the problem were the `A` instance the interpreter would complain about the `f` method and the stacktrace would be very different.